# Nextjs routing catchAll and slug folder within a route cannot co-exist?

Tags: javascript, next.js, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am converting my pages to ISR and come across an issue when using params and having to re-write the route to a dynamic route. For example, **article/?pageNumber=2** gets rewritten to **article/2** in middleware to combat this. However, my routing structure will now look like this:

```
[categories]/[slug]/index.ts
[categories/[...pageParams].ts
```

This means that the pageParams catches all routes and [slug] ends up being ignored. Is there a way around this at all?

Answer (score 2):

Adding ... to the route like in your example:

```js
 [...pageParams].tsx
```

tells next.js to catch all paths under that route for example it will catch:
article/a and article/a/b and article/a/b/c etc...

And since you're using another dynamic route (slug) under the same parent route, it will be caught by the catch-all path ...pageParams

To read more about catch-all routes check this section of the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes):

> Dynamic routes can be extended to catch all paths by adding three dots (...) inside the brackets. For example:
>
> pages/post/[...slug].js matches /post/a, but also /post/a/b,
> /post/a/b/c and so on

What I would usually do is create a static route /page and under it a dynamic route for the page number it should look like this:

```js
[categories]/page/[number].tsx
[categories]/[slug].tsx
```

Next js will give priority to the dynamic route /page/[slug] before /[slug]

If you want to handle route /page (which will be considered as a slug) you can create a redirect via next.config.js

```js
redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:categories/page",
        destination: "/:categories/page/1",
        permanent: true
      }
    ]
}
```

This way if a user entered the /page url it will be redirected to /page/1

Comment: yeah figured so, just wanted to get some clarification. Appreciate your reply - thank you :)